# Python функции и переменные

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, функции, переменные

есть код формата:

```
def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('span',class_='left')
    
    gamers = []
    for item in items:
        gamers.append({
            item.find('a').get_text(strip=True)
        })
    top_gamers = gamers[:10]
    return top_gamers
```

происходит парсинг данных из сайта, точнее из тега `<a>` и сохранение в переменную gamers
потом сохраняю данные, точнее первые 10 элементов в другую переменную, как мне использовать значения в этой переменной в другом месте кода? т.е. достать данных переменной из функции

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам надо результат функции сохранить в переменную и потом передавать их в другие функции

```
def foo(top_gamers):
    # Код

top_gamers = get_content(html)
foo(top_gamers)
```

Comment: данные которые я сохраню получается ведь массив, следом я хочу данные из массива по каждому элементу пристроить к переменной, я не намерен эту переменную использовать в другой функции

Comment: хочу потом сделать вот так

    ```top1 = top_gamers[0]
    top2 = top_gamers[1]
    top3 = top_gamers[2]
    top4 = top_gamers[3]
    top5 = top_gamers[4]
    top6 = top_gamers[5]
    top7 = top_gamers[6]
    top8 = top_gamers[7]
    top9 = top_gamers[8]
    top10 = top_gamers[9]```

и все

Comment: @St0rm1k так делать **не надо** лучше пусть они будут лежать в списке. так будет правильнее

Answer (score -4):

Используй глобальные функции

```
def my_func(a, b):
   global gamers
   ...
```

Comment: начать нужно с того, что это не глобальная функция, а глобальная переменная. во вторых, чтоб так писать нужно это переменную объявить вне функции, ибо это не `переменная доступна из функции`, а `переменная из общего пространства имен доступна функции в том числе на изменение`